# Unhandled exception in debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

During debugging my project, i am getting the an unhandled exception. I am new in debugging using visual studio 2017 , Can anyone give me any approach or idea to remove this exception? Due to this my application crashes. I am attaching the exact exception statement below.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76442552 in someprocess.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x1C00F258.
```

[image]

Comment: Hi guy, the exception is caused by your code and with the info which you provided, we  cannot handle it.Could you please [share a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us so that we can troubleshoot the issue more quickly.

Comment: Also, did you use Debug mode to debug the program?

Comment: No, i used release mode(x64) for debug the program.

Comment: try to use debug mode still happen? Besides, please provide a small,reproducible sample with us  and we could troubleshoot it more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

> Unhandled exception in debugging

**Usually**, the issue is caused by your code.And from the description, the error is from `info.hasException`.

**Please make sure** that when you define info property, you should set a default value to it like `NULL`;

You should check very carefully and make sure that `info` has value and its type is right.

Also, please provide a small sample about your project to help us troubleshoot the issue more quickly.